# How to get each course name in a grades table where I only have the id for course?

Tags: sql

I have a Grades table where I have the following fields:

-STUDENT_ID 
   -COURSE_ID 
   -FIRST_TERM 
   -SECOND_TERM 
   -FINAL

And a Course table:

-COURSE_ID 
   -NAME 
   -DEPARTMENT_ID

I'm trying to get all the grades for a particular student with grades for each course specified, I was wondering how do I get the name of each course?

This is how I get the grades but I want to include the course name also:

```
SELECT student_id,
       course_id,
       (first_term+second_term+final) AS "Total  Mark"
  FROM MARKS
  WHERE student_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT     s.student_id,
           s.course_id,
           c.course_name,
           (s.first_term+s.second_term+s.final) AS "Total  Mark"
FROM       marks s
INNER JOIN course c ON c.course_id = s.course_id
WHERE      s.student_id = 1
```

Make sure to prefix field names with table names when they are used in both tables (like for `course_id`). I have prefixed all fields with table aliases.

Table aliases are like short names for tables and you define them right after the table name in the `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT student_id, m.course_id,c.name as course_name, (first_term+second_term+final) AS "Total Mark" FROM MARKS M inner join course c on m.course_id = c.course_id WHERE student_id = 1;
```

Use an inner join between marks and course table to get name from course table.

Comment: M is an alias for Marks table

Comment: ORA-00904: "C"."ID": invalid identifier I get this error when I run the query with oracle 10g. What do I need to change to get it working for me?

Comment: I did that but it gives me another error. 
ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT student_id,
       course_id,
       name,
       (first_term+second_term+final) AS "Total  Mark"
  FROM MARKS m, Course c
  WHERE (student_id = 1) and c.course_id=m.course_id;
```